# files do not save in /media/data

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

New to Ubuntu, a free OS of greatness, I followed the step by step procedure in one of the online resources of Ubuntu for installing the OS. As instructed, I learned that I have to create the following spaces in the drive: 1.Root 2.Home 3.Swap.
Concerning Home partition, where it is said "your files are kept," the instruction is to enter in its MOUNT POINT: "/media/data." However, after the installation, when I'm trying to transfer all my files into the new OS, a window appeared noting, "The volume "Filesystem root" has only 95.8Mb disc space remaining."
What went wrong? Why are my files not saved in the Home partition?
Please help. I'm a newbie ubuntu user.

Answer (score 1):

Your personal files, such as documents, music, videos, and so forth, are saved in your home folder. A home partition contains users' home folders. System files, like the files that comprise all the installed programs, are not stored there.

If you made an extremely small partition for `/`, and you just installed, the best thing to do is delete the new partitions and install again.

Also, the mount point for `/home` is `/home`; if you created a partition and gave it the mount point `/media/data`, that's *not* `/home` and your home directory won't (and shouldn't) automatically be put there.

---

If you want, you can show us all your partitions and how they're being used by opening a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the commands:

```
mount
df -h
sudo parted -l
```

---

Then it *might* be possible for more specific advice to be given. But most likely, this is the advice that pertains:

1. Ubuntu can create its own partitions automatically. It does this very well. Especially if you don't know what partitions to create or how large to make them, letting Ubuntu's installer partition automatically is a good choice.

   *If you are going to partition manually:*
2. Whatever release of Ubuntu you are installing will specify how large the disk needs to be, to install. You should take this as the minimium size of the `/` partition. Usually the `/` partition should be much larger. If your disk is 50 GB or more, `/` should be 20 GB or larger. If your disk is 200 GB or more, `/` should be 70 GB or larger.
3. By default a swap partition is created. If you are partitioning manually, you should create one. It should be a few gigabytes large. There are many competing ideas about how to determine the best size of a swap partition; that is beyond the scope of this very basic advice. But Ubuntu can make, and choose the size for, its own swap partition too.
4. A separate home partition has the mount point `/home`. If you use one, make sure it's large enough for whatever you intend to put in it. `/home` contains the home folders associated with all the human user accounts on the machine. Most users put their documents and downloads in their home folder and Ubuntu defaults to facilitating this. You might also want to store potentially bigger collections of files in your home folder: music, videos, and so forth. (The other reasonable option is to put it on a separate hard drive.)

   Practically speaking, a separate home partition should usually be at least 30 GB, and much larger if you have the space and plan to store a lot of personal data (i.e., data that is maintained by you, rather than installed and updated by Ubuntu's package manager) on the system.